# How can I import the text of a file into a variable in javascript during compilation using webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have an application that requires the use of long string values that are ideally stored in a separate text file.

However, I'm kind of stumped as to how I can perform something like the following:

```
import fileText from './path/to/filename.txt'
```

and have the end result being something like:

```
var fileText = 'Long text string that was derived during compilation'
```

It wouldn't be ideal if I have to reconstruct the original text into a javascript file that returns the string as I'd like to not abandon the syntax highlighting of the original text file.

**Update:**

Using **raw-loader** worked like a charm except I was using typescript and it was throwing errors during compilation. Setting up the following typescript declaration ended up getting it working for me.

```
declare module "*.txt" {
    const content :string;
    export = content;
}
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you just need [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175900/how-do-you-import-a-text-file-into-typescript/75313118#75313118 for a full answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `raw-loader` and use it load `txt` files:

```
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

Add to rules:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.txt$/,
    use: 'raw-loader'
  }
]
```