# How do you import a text file into typescript?

Tags: typescript

As a minimal example, I want to import a text file into typescript and print it to the console without reading it using `fs`. Something like this:

```
import text from './foo.txt'

console.log(text)
```

I've found many examples of solutions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47705264/311156) and I have created a `typings.d.ts` file with the content

```
declare module '*.txt' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

But when I build the project I still see "error TS2307: Cannot find module './foo.txt'."

What am I missing?

Example repo here: https://github.com/gferreri/typescript-import-test

Comment: Possibly with a webpack [`raw-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/)?

Comment: I think a loader such as `raw-loader` is the second step of the complete puzzle. But the first step is getting `tsc` to stop complaining that it can't find the file.

Comment: why do you need to do this without `fs`? `foo.txt` is not a module, and so, accordingly, you can't import it.

Comment: Because I am building library code and I do not want to introduce the `fs` module to bring in a compile-time resource. In my case, `foo.txt` is a generated graphql schema file that just needs to be treated as a string constant.

Comment: Omg, I had the same problem and was trying to fix for 2 hours, and I was about to give up but tried tweaking your code and it just worked for me without editing it at all. Thank you so much

Comment: @djs, see the bottom of my answer. Look how pretty it is to just import the text file. And not have to worry about paths in environments, permissions, etc. The text file is a resource like any other resource; that's why webpack gives raw-loader, expressly for this purpose. However, it's tricky to set  up, hence my detailed answer

Comment: @Daniel, your comment is the 'omg I finally got it working. Good luck everyone!' meme. Please add what you did to get it working (LOL), so that you're not the living embodiment of a meme.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If the text file is a graphql schema, as noted in your comment, you can use [graphql-tag/loader](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#webpack-preprocessing-with-graphql-tagloader) with webpack. Couple that with proper typing for *.graphql files:

```
declare module '*.graphql' {
  import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';
  const value: DocumentNode;
  export = value;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to go this route, but even after adding the typing, I still see `TS2307: Cannot find module './schema.graphql'.` Maybe I don't understand how to add this typing correctly?

Comment: Just need to define it as an ambient module, in a `.d.ts` file. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules

Answer (score 2):

### [TypeScript][Webpack][CreateReactApp] Import file as text

It doesn't have to be `txt`. It can be any file extension not already handled by `webpack`.

If you aren't using `create react app`, you can just skip that step although I recommend keeping `webpack` config modifications into a separate file.

Otherwise, I found each of these steps to be necessary to get this working. I removed all unnecessary cruft.

You only have to do steps 1-7 one time per project.

1. [Terminal] get into your project directory: `cd ./my-app`
2. [Terminal] Install `raw-loader`: `npm i raw-loader --save-dev`
3. [Terminal][CreateReactApp=true] Install `react-app-rewired` so that your custom config isn't living in `node_modules`: `npm i react-app-rewired --save-dev`
4. [VS Code][CreateReactApp=true][package.json] change `start`, `build` and `test` scripts to use react-app-rewired: e.g., `"start": "react-app-rewired start"`. If you find this too radical, find your webpage.config.js and just modify that. But that incurs the risk it will get blown away. It won't survive a round trip to GitHub, for example.
5. [VS Code] Add `global.d.ts` to project `src`
6. [VS Code][CreateReactApp=true] Add `config-overrides.js` to project root `my-app`
7. [Terminal] build: `yarn build`
8. [VS Code] Add text file to project: `src/mydir/data.txt`
9. [VS Code][example.ts] import text file: `import mytext from './data.txt'`
10. [VS Code][example.ts] use text variable normally: `myFunc(mytext)`
11. [Terminal] run: `yarn run`

**global.d.ts**

```
declare module '*.txt' {}
```

**config-overrides.js**

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  const newRule = {
    test: /\.txt$/i,
    loader: 'raw-loader',
    options: {
      esModule: false,
    },
  }
  config.module.rules.find((r) => r.oneOf).oneOf.unshift(newRule)
  return config
}
```

**data.txt**

```
hello world
```

**example.ts**

```
import myText from './data.txt'

var result = myFund(myText)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me keep my GSLS shaders in a .frag file for ease but use them in my js app!

Answer (score -4):

One solution would be to explicitly read if from disk using `fs` - (this is easy if you're not planning on bundling the application using Webpack/similar).

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

const text = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './foo.txt'), 'utf-8');

console.log(text)
```

Comment: The question literally says "without fs".

Comment: Yeah, fair point.